# How to visualize orientation of 3d objects

Tags: geometry, soft-question, visualization

The way I visualize orientations of $1$- and $2$-dimensional objects is by an ant walking along a path.  For a $1$d object (like a line/ line segment/ etc), just place the ant on the line and confine it to walk in only one direction.  Then it only has two choices as to the direction it walks -- those are the two orientations.  For a $2$d object (like a plane/ planar triangle/ etc), place the ant inside the object and then confine it to walk in a circle.  It can either walk in a clockwise or counterclockwise circle -- those are the two orientations.

How can I similarly (or completely differently) visualize orientations of $3$d objects?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [the right-hand rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule#Coordinate_orientation) has some illustrations of the orientations or *chirality* of coordinate axes in 3D.  It might help to inform your discussion of this topic.

Comment: I understand the right hand rule and can use it.  I'm specifically looking for an answer that doesn't require me to appeal to the directions of coordinate axes to figure out the orientation of an object.

Comment: Although that does give me an idea of how to visualize it with ants.  Place the ant inside the object and start it rotating about the axis running through from its stinger to its head (it doesn't matter which way you start it rotating).  Then confine the ant to move in one direction along that axis.  If the direction it chooses with respect to the direction that it's rotating follows the right-hand rule then that's one orientation and if not then that's the other.  Hmmm... that's interesting.